# Mapping lists in my Mapper class using using AutoMapper

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, automapper

I am using `ASP.NET MVC 3` and `AutoMapper`.

In my category controller I return a list of categories and I want to map each category to a category view model which is used in my grid.  I have my own mapper class method that accepts the source, source type and destination type and then does the mapping of single objects.  How would I add and additional method so that I can map lists?

For example, if I want to map a single category to my category edit view model then the following mapping will be used:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<CategoryCreateViewModel, Category>();
```

In my controller I would map the 2 like this:

```
Category category = (Category)categoryMapper.Map(viewModel, typeof(CategoryCreateViewModel), typeof(Category));
```

This is what my mapping method looks like:

```
public class CategoryMapper : ICategoryMapper
{
     static CategoryMapper()
     {
          Mapper.CreateMap<Category, CategoryCreateViewModel>();
          Mapper.CreateMap<Category, CategoryViewModel>();
          Mapper.CreateMap<CategoryCreateViewModel, Category>();
     }

     public object Map(object source, Type sourceType, Type destinationType)
     {
          return Mapper.Map(source, sourceType, destinationType);
     }

     // I have been trying to get this right but not working
     //public object Map(object source, IEnumerable<Type> sourceType, IEnumerable<Type> destinationType)
     //{
     //     return Mapper.Map(sourceType, destinationType);
     //}
}
```

I want to add another method where I can map lists.  How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to use my IMapper methods like I mentioned above.  With the help of `Darin Dimitrov` I got this to work.  Here is my controller code:

```
public ActionResult JsonGetParentCategoryList()
{
     IEnumerable<Category> categoryList = categoryService.GetAll();

     // Mapping
     IEnumerable<CategoryViewModel> viewModelList = (IEnumerable<CategoryViewModel>)
          categoryMapper.Map(
               categoryList,
               typeof(IEnumerable<Category>),
               typeof(IEnumerable<CategoryViewModel>)
     );

     JsonEncapsulatorDto<CategoryViewModel> data = new JsonEncapsulatorDto<CategoryViewModel>
     {
          DataResultSet = viewModelList
     };

     return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

It works with my current IMapper Map method.

Answer (score 2):

AutoMapper knows how to map lists, you don't need any extra code.

As long as you provide the mapping for the single object, it will work.

E.g:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source,Dest>();
```

Then:

```
var mappedCollection = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Source>,IEnumerable<Dest>>(items);
```

And it will work.

Comment: Please look at my CategoryMapper class: Can you please heklp me write the Map method to accept parameters and to map lists.  I have commented out code in my class, please can you help modify the method so that it does the mapping?  I am working from an interface and don't want it to accept a type of T.

Comment: @BrendanVogt - why do you need a "mapper" class? Why not called `Mapper.Map` directly from your controller like i have done above? Your making your job way more difficult than it has to be.

Comment: Have you ever that about what would happen if you have to change your mapper API?  Then you need to go and change it in every controller.  It's better to have my own mapper class and set up the mappings there.

Comment: @Brendan - good point. Can't envision changing anytime soon though. And if i did, i'd just use VS refactoring/replacing. Take your point though.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var maplist= Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<TSource>, IEnumerable<TDestination>>(IEnumerable<TSource>source);
```

i'm not sure but try something like

```
var category = CategoryMapper.Map(viewModel, CategoryCreateViewModel, Category);

public object Map(object source, IEnumerable<T> sourceType, IEnumerable<T> destinationType)
     {
         return Mapper.Map<sourceType,destinationType>(source);
     }
```

Comment: Please provide the full method code where you want me to try this.  Let it fit into my CategoryMapper class.

Comment: Thanks. I need to supply T and if I want to go this route then I have to change my mapper class, and I don't want to.  Can you please change your method so that it fitst into what I currently have it, like the method that I use to map single entities.  Thanks.